# Sorting and ordering an array with different criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to implement sorting and order to an array.

The challenge which I am facing is that I have 5 criteria on which to base my sorting, which are:

1. `due_date === 1000`
2. `status && is_approved(boolean)`
3. `is_overdue`(boolean checking with
   `date-fns` using the `due_date`)
4. `due_date` (either null, or number)
5. `is_approved`

What I would like to achieve is to create a sorting function which orders the above criteria as the following (from highest to lowest):

1. `due_date === 1000`
2. `is_overdue` (I am using isAfter of the date-fns which returns a boolean)
3. `status === 'DONE' && !is_approved`
4. `due_date` starting from lowest to highest (ignore the null values)
5. `is_approved === true`
6. any other remaining object

I was thinking of perhaps running `.map` method, and appending a `ranking` value for each of the object by checking the criteria, but there must be a way of doing this in single iteration with `.sort` method. I already checked other StackOverflow threads, but most of their data is relatively simple such as age, name etc.

```
[
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000,
      is_approved: true,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE',
    },
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'IN PROGRESS',
    },
    {
      due_date: 1000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000,
      is_approved: true,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE',
    },
    {
      due_date: null,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
  ]
```

Which I want to transform to;

```
[
    {
      due_date: 1000, // By due_date 1000 - highest ranking
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true, // Is overdue - second highest
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: null,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true, // Is overdue - second highest
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000,
      is_approved: false, // Is not yet approved
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE', // and Is DONE
    },
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'IN PROGRESS',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000, // Lowest ranked
      is_approved: true, // Is APPROVED approved
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE', // and is DONE
    },
  ]
```

Comment: please add some data and show the problem.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added the example data and the desired result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort add your logic in the compareFunction as which criteria will be used to decide whether `a` should come before `b` or other way. just return -1, 1, 0 to indicate this and sorting will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deltas of boolean value are reversed. Theat mean if you like to sort `true` to top, you need to use `b - a`.

You could have a look to the wanted propeties and their values:

- `due_date === 1000` (desc)
- `is_overdue` (desc)
- `is_approved` (asc)
- `status === 'DONE' + !is_approved` (sum asc)
- `due_date === null` (asc)
- `due_date` (desc)

```js
const
    data = [{ due_date: 150000, is_approved: false, is_overdue: true, status: 'TODO' }, { due_date: 200000, is_approved: true, is_overdue: false, status: 'DONE' }, { due_date: 150000, is_approved: false, is_overdue: false, status: 'IN PROGRESS' }, { due_date: 1000, is_approved: false, is_overdue: true, status: 'TODO' }, { due_date: 200000, is_approved: false, is_overdue: false, status: 'DONE' }, { due_date: null, is_approved: false, is_overdue: true, status: 'TODO' }];

data.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.due_date === 1000) - (a.due_date === 1000) ||
    b.is_overdue - a.is_overdue ||
    a.is_approved - b.is_approved ||
    (a.status === 'DONE' + !a.is_approved) - (b.status === 'DONE' + !b.is_approved) ||
    (a.due_date === null) - (b.due_date === null) ||
    b.due_date - a.due_date 
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: With bit of a refactoring, it did wonders. Thank you for the answer!
`data.sort((a, b) =>
          (b.due_date === 1000) - (a.due_date === 1000) ||
    isAfter( Date.now(), fromUnixTime(b.due_date)) - isAfter( Date.now(), fromUnixTime(a.due_date)) ||
    (b.status === 'DONE' && !b.is_approved) - (a.status === 'DONE' && !a.is_approved) ||
    (b.due_date && !b.is_approved) - (a.due_date && !a.is_approved) ||
      (b.due_date === null && !b.is_approved) - (a.due_date === null && !a.is_approved) ||
       b.is_approved - a.is_approved
        )`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a sorting function

I've implemented the first two requirements I leave the rest to you

Probably it needs a bit of refactoring but you get the idea

```js
const data = [
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000,
      is_approved: true,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE',
    },
    {
      due_date: 150000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'IN PROGRESS',
    },
    {
      due_date: 1000,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
    {
      due_date: 200000,
      is_approved: true,
      is_overdue: false,
      status: 'DONE',
    },
    {
      due_date: null,
      is_approved: false,
      is_overdue: true,
      status: 'TODO',
    },
  ]
  
  
 const sortingFn = (a, b) => {
  if(a.due_date === 1000){
    return -1
  }
  if(b.due_date === 1000){
    return 1
  }
  
  if(a.is_overdue){
    return -1
  }
 
   if(b.is_overdue){
    return 1
  }
  //the rest of the conditions
 }
 
 data.sort(sortingFn)
 console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer! This works too. It's just that it has quite some DRY code. The answer from Nina Scholz works in quite a nice way.